# Assign value to a column based of other columns from the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, conditional-statements

with a dataframe, I have one column, called `TM52_fail`

```
2
1
-
1 & 2
1 & 2 & 3
-
-
3
etc.
```

and I would like to create an additional column, called `TM52_fail_norm`, whose content depends on the content of the column `TM52_fail`.
My attempt (which includes the conditional filling):

```
def str_to_number(x):
    if x=="1" or x=="2" or x=="3":
        return 1
    elif x=="1 & 2" or x=="2 & 3" or x=="1 & 3":
        return 2
    elif x=="1 & 2 & 3":
        return 3
    else:
        return 0

df['TM52_fail_norm'] = ""
df['TM52_fail_norm'].apply(lambda x: str_to_number(x for x in df['TM52_fail']))
```

returns an empty column (I presume as a result of `df['TM52_fail_norm'] = ""`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need cast to string by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then apply function `str_to_number`:

```
df['new'] = df['TM52_fail_norm'].astype(str).apply(str_to_number)
print (df)
  TM52_fail_norm  new
0              2    1
1              1    1
2              -    0
3          1 & 2    2
4      1 & 2 & 3    3
5              -    0
6              -    0
7              3    1
```

Another solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`, last need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `0` and cast to `int`:

```
d = {'1':1,'2':1,'3':1,'1 & 2':2, '2 & 3':2, '1 & 3':2,'1 & 2 & 3':3}

df['new'] = df['TM52_fail_norm'].map(d)
df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
  TM52_fail_norm  new
0              2    1
1              1    1
2              -    0
3          1 & 2    2
4      1 & 2 & 3    3
5              -    0
6              -    0
7              3    1
```

**Timings**:

```
#[800000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [315]: %timeit (jez1(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 63 ms per loop

In [316]: %timeit (df['TM52_fail_norm'].astype(str).apply(str_to_number))
1 loop, best of 3: 518 ms per loop

#http://stackoverflow.com/a/40176883/2901002
In [345]: %timeit (df.TM52_fail_norm.str.count('\d+'))
1 loop, best of 3: 707 ms per loop


def jez1(df):
    d = {'1':1,'2':1,'3':1,'1 & 2':2, '2 & 3':2, '1 & 3':2,'1 & 2 & 3':3}

    df['new'] = df['TM52_fail_norm'].map(d)
    df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(0).astype(int)
    return (df)

print (jez1(df))
```

Comment: Thank you. I think second solution can be faster.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `df.TM52_fail.str.count('\d+')`

It seems that what you really want is to count the number of digits. Here, pandas' `.str` accessor methods ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html), [summary of `.str` methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary)) are really helpful!

I suppose `TM52_fail` is of dtype `str`; otherwise you can cast it with `.astype(str)`, as suggested by @jezrael:

```
# setup
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'TM52_fail':[
    "2", "1", "", "1 & 2", "1 & 2 & 3", "", "", "3"]})

# Use regex \d+ to find 1 or more consecutive digits
df['TM52_fail_norm2'] = df.TM52_fail.str.count('\d+')
```

#### Timings

```
Regex: 155 µs per loop
 jez1: 999 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yes, it is faster in small dataframe, but in larger the slowiest. See update in my timings. But I think it is good solution.